# next-i18next re-rendering _app.js after page load with getstaticprops

Tags: next.js, internationalization, next-i18next

I'm using next-i18next and the app.

the _app.js is called again after every getstaticprops function.

Why is that?

Thank you

Comment: Have you found anything?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when navigating between a page where getStaticProps (or getServerSideProps) is not defined and a page where getStaticProps is defined.